# How can I pull the microwave forward in a combination oven to replace the microwave light?

Tags: appliances, oven, microwave-oven, light-bulb

How do I pull forward the microwave from this RMC305PVS (30-inch Combination Microwave-Wall Oven)? Trying to change the lightbulb.

Optionally: How might I get a link to a technical service manual for the Whirlpool RMC305PVS or equivalent, if possible (?)

I have removed:

- 2 black plastic grills: 1) center vent (between lower oven & upper microwave); and 2) control vent (between upper microwave & control panel)
- Side trim & bottom vent trim pieces
- Two screws at the bottom of the microwave holding it in place
- Various screws for the upper control panel & lifted it out of the way

However, unlike YouTube videos (e.g., [this excellent instructional video by AppliancePartsPros](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uMEixNvakM&t=124s)), when I pull or shake the upper microwave--even with force--it does not move forward.

For what it is worth, I have pulled the entire combination enclosure (microwave & oven all at once) enclosure forward a few inches, to get at a few screws on the control panel.

It seems like I should be able to pull the microwave forward. The microwave seems below two metal sheets which the control panel does not seem to obstruct: 1) Top cover (part 4450378); and 2) Exhaust duct (part 4451634).

Reference:

Parts list:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/sm-backend-production-attachments/parts-list-W10269269-RevC.pdf

[image: Control board moved out of the way and resting on top of cabinet enclosure]

[image: Service tag showing model number]

[image: Microwave door opened after removing side trim pieces, showing the cabinet rails]

[image: Front view after removing front trim pieces and removing oven door. Control board is resting on top of the cabinet enclosure.]

Comment: What bulb? Page 11 in the [manual](https://www.whirlpool.com/content/dam/global/documents/200803/owners-manual-W10192043A.pdf) covers the oven bulb (which is easily accessible). Is there a bulb in the microwave you're trying to get at?

Comment: Thank you, it is the microwave bulb, part 4375348 (reference is [pages 7 & 8 on the PDF parts list link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sm-backend-production-attachments/parts-list-W10269269-RevC.pdf#page=7), illustration #53). As a video reference, you can see the bulb replacement via the linked YouTube video by AppliancePartsPros which pulls the microwave to access its top where a spring clip holds the bulb in place. I have visually confirmed that is where the bulb & the spring clip is on this model, but I cannot pull the microwave forward to access it.